# Understanding why Prettier are breaking lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

I have set line length to 140 and Prettier are still breaking this lines

```
private displayDetailsSource: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
displayDetailsObservable: Observable<boolean> = this.displayDetailsSource.asObservable();
```

**When I save:**

```
private displayDetailsSource: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(
    false
  );
  displayDetailsObservable: Observable<
    boolean
  > = this.displayDetailsSource.asObservable();
```

This makes the code very hard to read. I have default tslint in my angular project and line lengths set to 140 in the tslint file and in VS Code settings.

I love Prettier but sometimes the rules can be tuff to understand

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLWcBOAzAhmOAAgDEIJDgAdKAB01QDdd5CATVAZxoBtcBPACJwYuVNw4BlCAFdMBJIQBCcABa4GqCJgnSARgCs4YGAB5dZbnFxQAfIQC8hKHADuS1es3a9h4wAo8cTgASgBuanYuXkFhUXEAeV0OLCZdSwVE5MxUyzMLK1sHQhgVTgA6SJ5+IRExSRk5ODLcDkyU3DS4PzDCQmoAX2oQABoQCBoYTSgOZFBcTEwIFwAFeYQZlHUIVFYRkF1MfABrYQkafHQAc2QYTGk4UfQsmGXDy4BbXGRA5NH9DgAHopDmATjAJLh3nAADLoODfXBBUbnTBZZAgGB8GhwDhgegTPZ0dAwADqOxKyAAjAAWAAMyMWyRJhxo6LoOJS8NGmDgAEdpKgea9cB8vkgfg8QMl3qgbndJRwrpYAIrSCDwBFIjEdMmsClIABMo1ucSuAGEIO9PuioNAuSBpMkACodDYS-r9IA

It's likely another VSCode plugin causing this

Comment: Thanks I can see that it should work. Must be a conflict between tslint and VS Code settings.